# Button click on RepositoryItemButtonEdit in gridview doesn't trigger any events in DevExpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a gridview with 3 columns with multiple rows.  The first two columns consists of the client's id number and the 
client's name. The third column is a RepositoryItemButtonEdit button that, when is clicked, will delete the client from 
that row.

I've declared a `RepositoryItemButtonEdit` the following way.

```
Dim WithEvents buttonDelete As RepositoryItemButtonEdit
buttonDelete = New RepositoryItemButtonEdit

buttonDelete.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor
buttonDelete.Buttons(0).Kind = ButtonPredefines.Glyph
buttonDelete.Buttons(0).Caption = "Supprimer"
AddHandler buttonDelete.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click
```

I've added it to the third column the following way.

```
Dim unbColumn As GridColumn = gvException.Columns.AddField("Delete")
                unbColumn.VisibleIndex = gvException.Columns.Count
                unbColumn.ColumnEdit = buttonDelete
                gvException.OptionsView.ShowButtonMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways
```

The 'button click' event is captured the following way:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles buttonDelete.Click 
    MessageBox.Show("Hello world")
end sub
```

When I launch the application, I see a 'Delete' button for each row.

PROBLEM: However, I only get a 'Hello World' messagebox
when I click on the 'Delete' button from the first row, not when I click on the 'Delete' button from the other rows.

Comment: Remove the `Handles buttonDelete.Click` from your event signature and it should work just fine.

Comment: @BishopBarber After removing the Handles buttonDelete.Click event, nothing happens when I click on any button.

Comment: Try setting e's type to `ButtonPressedEventArgs` instead of `EventArgs`

Comment: @BishopBarber After changing e's type to ButtonPressedEventArgs :Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs' when I click on first button.  Nothing happens when I click on other buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your `AddHandler` statement. It should be `AddHandler buttonDelete.ButtonClick, AddressOf Me.Button_Click`. The `Click` event fires when clicking the editor, while the `ButtonClick` event occurs when the editor button is clicked. Although, if you didn't get the error when clicking the other buttons, I suspect there's another mistake I'm overlooking. Can you confirm?

Comment: @BishopBarber After changing the AddHandler to 'buttonDelete.ButtonClick', nothing has changed: still nothing when I click on other buttons.  So just to refresh, as of now, my AddHandler is set to 'buttonDelete.ButtonClick' and my method's signature is: 
 `Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)`

Comment: Leave your event parameter `e`'s type to `ButtonPressedEventArgs`. [See here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_ButtonClicktopic).

Comment: @BishopBarber `e`s type is now set to `ButtonPressedEventArgs` .  Still not getting anything when I click on other buttons though.

Comment: starting to think that this might be because only one `RepositoryItemButtonEdit` button has actually been created (eventhough I 'visually' see a button for each row) .  In other words, I would need to create one button per row?  (This would explain why I only get and message box when I click on first button)

Comment: I have copied your code and it works properly as expected on my side.

Comment: Does your `gvException.OptionsSelection` have `MultiSelectMode = CellSelect` and `MultiSelect = True` options?

Comment: @nempoBu4 .  No.  `MultiSelectMode` wasn't set to `CellSelect` and `MultiSelect` was set to `False`.

Comment: Found solution or rather the problem.  Had some code to prevent editing of certain cells that interfered with the raising of the click event.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Add **buttonDelete.ButtonPressed** event instead of **buttonDelete.Click** event.

What I have tried is below and working fine:

```
Dim buttonDelete As New RepositoryItemButtonEdit

buttonDelete.Buttons.Clear()
buttonDelete.ButtonsStyle = BorderStyles.UltraFlat
buttonDelete.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor

Dim edtrBtn As EditorButton = New EditorButton()
edtrBtn.Kind = ButtonPredefines.Glyph
edtrBtn.Caption = "Supprimer"

AddHandler buttonDelete.ButtonPressed, AddressOf RepositoryItemButtonEdit_Pressed

buttonDelete.Buttons.Add(edtrBtn)
```

Pressed event:

```
Private Sub RepositoryItemButtonEdit_Pressed(sender As Object, e As ButtonPressedEventArgs)

''' Your Logic Here

End Sub
```

It should work. Rest goes ok.